# Tensor manipulation software

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, tensor-calculus, software

Does anyone know of any free tensor manipulation software for use in General relativity? e.g GR tensor
(this includes software that needs programs such as mathematica or matlab to use)

Comment: Mathics is basically free Mathematica: https://mathics.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SageManifolds](http://sagemanifolds.obspm.fr/) is a package included in the free computer algebra system  [SageMath 7.5](http://www.sagemath.org/index.html). It is rather powerful and is developed by Eric Gourgoulhon and others.

There are various [examples](http://sagemanifolds.obspm.fr/examples.html) available and quiet a few are common GR problems.

I myself never worked with it but I know that it is quite popular in the numerical relativity community. With the examples it should be rather easy to get started and the whole package is [well documented](http://sagemanifolds.obspm.fr/doc/reference/manifolds/index.html).